# Android Google Maps Marker: Released unknown imageData reference

Tags: android, svg, google-maps-markers, bitmapimage, xml-drawable

I'm trying to add support to tablets in my app and run into IllegalArgumentException thrown by this line of code:

```
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow_green_10by19))
```

The method .fromResource works fine with the R.drawable.arrow_green_10by19 from an image file (png) but when the png is replaced with the vector file arrow_green_10by19.xml (which renders fine in the Android Studio IDE) it generates a runtime as mentioned.

Does anybody knows how to implement a vector resource in the BitmapDescriptorFactory and could help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem but I realized that on my device with API 16 it works fine  but with API 21 it crashes. Finally it works in both devices using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35347960/5502014). Here the code:

```java
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

and this:

```java
private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
    } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
        return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
    }
}
```

So I combined those 2 functions in this way:

```java
private Marker addMark(LatLng latLng, String title) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_place_24dp);
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
            .title(title)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
            .draggable(true));

    return marker;
}
```

Where `R.drawable.ic_place_24dp` is a vector asset (.xml), not a .png

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's better now :)

Comment: It is way way better now. Thanks for that. And an upvote for the effort