# Error inflating MaterialAnimatedSwitch

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-switch

I am building an app, in which I have used animated switch button by glomadrain.
When I was done with my coding I got following error:

> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object
>   reference at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:750)                                                                                  at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPainter.initBitmap(IconPainter.java:41)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPainter.init(IconPainter.java:36)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPainter.(IconPainter.java:30)
>   11-25 14:05:04.032 4625-4625/com.example.surajnath.taproute
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.painter.IconPressPainter.(IconPressPainter.java:30)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.initPainters(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:79)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.init(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:65)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.init(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:90)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch.(MaterialAnimatedSwitch.java:54)

Here  my code regarding to the map and the switch :

```
<com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:id="@+id/location_switch"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off_black_24dp"
    app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
    app:base_release_color="@color/baseReleaseColor"
    app:base_press_color="@color/basePressColor"
    app:ball_release_color="@color/ballReleaseColor"
    app:ball_press_color="@android:color/white"/>
```

Comment: give us the layout file. you are probably doing mistake in `location_switch` view in your layout.

Comment: You are passing an invalid/unexpected drawable with `app:icon_press`.

Comment: yes @AmitUpadhyay and azizbekian i am using what you both have said  
what i have to change Please tell me :D

Comment: my layout code in  a this  link
https://pastebin.com/auUbcGPM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using a vector drawable as an input to `app:icon_press` and `app:icon_release`, whereas the library does not support vector drawable.

You have to either fork the library and perform [necessary changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244327/1083957) when creating a `Bitmap`, or you can provide a non-vector drawable as an input to those parameters.