# Trying make Android Uber app clone from Edmtdev, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo,android.view.InflateException

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, geofire

I am a newbie in Android development

Logcat:

```
com.example.androuber E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.androuber, PID: 19270
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androuber/com.example.androuber.Welcome}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:658)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:801)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:877)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:498)
        at com.android.internal.policy.HwPhoneWindow.setContentView(HwPhoneWindow.java:342)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2941)
        at com.example.androuber.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:78)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

This the Welcome.java.78:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
```

activity_welcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Welcome"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">


    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
<com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
    android:id="@+id/location_switch"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off"
    app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on"
    app:base_release_color="@color/baseReleaseColor"
    app:base_press_color="@color/basePressColor"
    app:ball_release_color="@color/ballReleaseColor"
    app:ball_press_color="@android:color/white"
    />
</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</fragment>
```

`OnCreate` of `Welcome.java` where are occurring:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



        //init view
       location_switch = (MaterialAnimatedSwitch) findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
        location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(boolean isOnline) {
                if (isOnline){
                    startLocationUpdate();
                    displayLocation();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You Are Online",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                else {
                    stopLocationUpdates();
                    mCurrent.remove();
                    Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(),"You Are Offline",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
        geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);

        setUpLocation();

    }
```

mainactivity Login block

```
private void showLoginDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("SIGN IN");
        dialog.setMessage("Please Use Email To sign in");

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View login_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_login,null);


        final MaterialEditText  edtEmail = (MaterialEditText) login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
        final MaterialEditText  edtPassword = (MaterialEditText) login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);


        dialog.setView(login_layout);

        // set Button
        dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        //set disable button sign in if in processing

                        btnSignUP.setEnabled(false);




                        //check validation
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtEmail.getText().toString())) {
                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please Enter Email Address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            return;
                        }


                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please Enter Password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            return;
                        }

                        if (edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6) {
                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Password too short!!!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            return;
                        }

                       final android.app.AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(MainActivity.this).build();
                        waitingDialog.show();

                        //login
                        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtEmail.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString())
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                        waitingDialog.dismiss();

                                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Welcome.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }) .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                waitingDialog.dismiss();
                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Failed "+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                                //Activate Sign up Button
                                btnSignUP.setEnabled(true);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Have you added dependency to this library in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
android:id="@+id/location_switch"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off"
app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on"
app:base_release_color="@color/baseReleaseColor"
app:base_press_color="@color/basePressColor"
app:ball_release_color="@color/ballReleaseColor"
app:ball_press_color="@android:color/white"
/>
```

I think you have used some attribute which is not provided by this library, remove all the custom attributes and check if it working or not, then you can apply your attribute one by one.

Comment: app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off"
app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on" this were the causing trouble

Answer (score 0):

Check this : [Error inflating MaterialAnimatedSwitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484108/error-inflating-materialanimatedswitch)

I think it already has been answered here.

Answer (score 0):

You added lib to the project?:
In project build.gradle :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

In app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
```