# Change application/window label and icon without change of launcher shortcut

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-drawable, android-launcher

Is it possible to change Android application window title/label and its icon without a change of launcher icon and application name shown on application shortcut?

[image]

I mean the icons and window names as shown on the screenshot above. **I am not referring to ActionBar** (if exist), which is a part of layout.

Is it possible to change this dynamically by code? Is it possible to change it for each activity separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lollipop added the `TaskDescription` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.TaskDescription.html

In any activity, you can write something like this:

```
ActivityManager.TaskDescription description = 
        new ActivityManager.TaskDescription("test", null, 0xff0000ff);

setTaskDescription(description);
```

Some notes:

- The title you pass will continue to show in the "recents" view, even if you navigate to another activity deeper in the hierarchy
- Passing `null` for the icon will leave the default icon in place.
- The color only applies to the current activity

Comment: **Looks good!** How can I use this method with vector drawable icon?

Comment: I'd check out answers to questions like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33696488/8298909