# Using Android native image from a NativeScript plugin

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I'm writing a NativeScript plugin for the Stripe library. On Android, I can't figure out how to turn a resource ID from the native library into a drawable image.

One of the calls I make returns an ID obtained from R.drawable.xxx. The image is in the native library's resources. I want to turn that into an image I can draw using the  tag.

I have tried this code:

```
import { android as androidApp } from "application";
let res = ...; // obtained from native library
let image = android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
  androidApp.foregroundActivity.getResources(),
  res);
```

but `decodeResource()` returns `null`. The native library is able to draw the same image, so somehow the resource is getting into the app. I just don't know how to access it from my code.

Note: On iOS this same call returns a UIImage, which is working correctly. I wish Stripe had been more consistent between their iOS and Android APIs!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Turns out my diagnosis was incorrect. The resource was being found, but it was a `VectorDrawable` and `decodeResource()` is unable to properly decode it.

The technique for converting a `VectorDrawable` to a `Bitmap` posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable) works.