# How to draw ImageVector on Canvas jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am converting SVG to vector asset by importing it to android studio. How can I draw that vector to canvas with jetpack compose. The only option I see is drawImage, which only takes ImageBitmap. But this is a vector and not a bitmap, so is there a way to just draw ImageVector.

```
val logoVector: ImageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.diasyst_logo)
```

Comment: You can get bitmap from ImageVector.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable

Comment: Is there a more normal way to just draw vector, instead of converting? It just doesn't seem optimal? Also the link above shows examples for Drawable not ImageVector

Comment: Is [AndroidView](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/viewinterop/androidview/) suitable for you？If you only want to disaply a VectorDrawable.

Comment: I would like to draw it on canvas

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can wrap your `ImageVector` into a `VectorPainter`, which is able to render to the standard compose Canvas.

```kotlin
val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    with(painter) {
        draw(painter.intrinsicSize)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing an `ImageVector` on a Canvas isn't directly possible.

The most straightforward approach for displaying and tinting the vector is using **[VectorPainter](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/vector/VectorPainter)**. Here's an example:

```
val painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.Add)
val tint = remember { ColorFilter.tint(Color.Red) }

Spacer(modifier = Modifier
       .size(100.dp,100.dp)
       .drawBehind {

           with(painter) {
                draw(
                    size = painter.intrinsicSize,
                    alpha = .5f, // optional
                    colorFilter = tint // optional
                )
            }

       })
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not strictly required to draw in `Canvas`, the `Icon` and `Image` Composables accept a vector graphics resource.

```
Icon(
 imageVector = ...
 contentDescription = ""
)

Image(
 imageVector = ...
 contentDescription = ""
)
```

Other than that, the only way is to basically convert the vector to a format you can use inside `drawImage` method of `Canvas`. I know you are concerned about performance and optimization, but rest assured, there's no problem using the conversion method